# Store ESX5 images on a NAS?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a basic NAS device ([Buffallo LinkStation Duo](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/network-storage/home-and-small-office/linkstation-pro-duo-1)) that can only present SMB fileshares to the network. For testing annd for getting a dying physical machine working I would like to store my VMDK on here. Is that possible, or will I have to find some way of presenting this as an iSCSI target of some sort?

I've only used iSCSI or local storage in the past, but this isn't possible at the moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont even think it is possible to mount a SMB share as storage en ESX..

And the performance would be terrible.

You should either go for some NFS storage, or iSCSI/local storage.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll have to push for this. It shouldn't cost much to stick some more disks into the old Proliant DL380GS.

Comment: It's a pity you went for that specific model as Buffalo do offer other similar models that support iSCSI and/or NFS such as their Terastation Duo (http://www.buffalotech.com/products/network-storage/business/terastation-duo-2).

Comment: It's the old "using stuff we have lying around" method :) I've managed to avert the crisis for now, so a smarter device is on the way.

Answer (score 2):

Ack, many NAS systems do NFS, and that works OK for ESXi. I would strongly recommend you set up dedicated NICs and a dedicated switch for NFS... it might also help to get a NAS and switch that can deal with jumbo frames.

Comment: Just make sure that if you use jumbo frames, set it on the vSwitch on the ESXi too - otherwise you'll end up without hair trying to figure out why it doesnt work. Im speaking of experience :)

Comment: And it might not even be necessary - GBit wirespeed throughput is perfectly achievable with standard frames and a well set up Linux NFS server. But I would still advise to buy equipment that supports it in case you need a bit more performance ... BTW, resist the temptation to run several ESXi hosts off a small NFS server, NFS can *really* choke if overloaded concurrently...